# Expectation of dependent Bernoulli sum

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I want to estimate the expected value of the following sum of random variables,

$$ Y = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i $$

where each $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable. In particular,

$$ X_1 = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{with prob. } 1/N \\
  0, & \text{with prob. }  1 - 1/N \end{cases} $$

and for all $2 \leq i \leq N$

$$ X_i = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{with prob. } p_i \\
  0, & \text{with prob. } 1 - p_i \end{cases} $$

where

$$ p_i = \begin{cases} p_{i-1} + 1/N, & \text{if } X_{i-1} = 0 \\
  1/N, & \text{if } X_{i-1} = 1 \end{cases} $$

I have computed the value for $ N=2 $ and $ N=3 $. For $ N = 2 $,

$$
  \mathbb{E}[Y] = 1 \left[ \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right) \frac{2}{N} + \frac{1}{N} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{N} \right)  \right] + 2 \frac{1}{N^2} = \frac{5}{4}
$$

where the first term corresponds to the sequences $(01)$ and $(10)$, while the second to $(11)$.

For $ N=3 $, here are the calculations

$$ 
\begin{gather}
\mathbb{E}[Y] = \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)\frac{3}{N} + 2 \times \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\frac{2}{N} \frac{1}{N} + 2 \times \frac{1}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\frac{2}{N} + 3 \times \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{N} + \left(1 - \frac{1}{N}\right)\frac{2}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) + \frac{1}{N}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right) + 2 \times \frac{1}{N} \frac{1}{N} \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right) \\
 = \frac{3}{N^3} - \frac{6}{N^2} + \frac{6}{N} \\
N=3 \rightarrow = \frac{39}{27} 
\end{gather}
$$

This results from the sequences (001), (011), (101), (111), (010), (100), (110).

Is there any way to proceed farther?

Comment: Your approach involves $2^N$ terms, one for each possible sequence.  However, it should be possible to write a recurrence that has only $N^2$ terms, indexed on the number of flips so far and the length of the current streak of $0$s.  Still not a closed-form though.  Would you be interested in that?

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to get a (non-trivial, e.g. N) upper bound?

Comment: A slightly less trivial upper bound would be $E[Y] = \sum p_i \le (1 + 2 + \cdots + N) / N = {N+1 \over 2}$...  But I would be shocked if the actual answer is linear.  (In fact I would not be surprised if the actual answer turns out to be constant, as $N \to \infty$.)

Answer (score 1):

**MY TRY**

We first look at $ P\{ Y=i\}$, i.e., $Y$ has exactly $i$ ones and $N-i$ zeros. The probability corresponding to ones is $N^{-i}$. The probability corresponding to zeros depends on number and size of blocks of zeros. There can be at most $i+1$ blocks of size between 0 and $N-i$, as we already have $i$ ones. Further, the probability corresponding to a block of size $a_k$ is $(a_k+1)!N^{-a_k} $. Thus, we have
\begin{align}
 P\{ Y=i\} &= N^{-i}\prod_{\substack{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i+1}\geq 0\\ \sum_{k=1}^{i+1} a_k=N-i} }1-\frac{(a_k+1)!}{N^{a_k}}\\
&= N^{-N}\prod_{\substack{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i+1i}\geq 0\\ \sum_{k=1}^{i+1} a_k=N-i} } N^N-(a_k+1)!
\end{align}
Also, we have the following:
\begin{align}
E\{Y\} = \sum_{i=0}^N i P\{ Y=i\} = N^{-N} \sum_{i=0}^N i  \prod_{\substack{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{i+1}\geq 0\\ \sum_{k=1}^{i+1} a_k=N-i} } N^N-(a_k+1)!
\end{align}
I don't know how to simplify it further!

Comment: Actually the probability of a sequence with $i$ 1 is not $N^{-i}$. Suppose you have N=3 and consider the sequence (1,0,0): here the 1 has probability 1/N. Now, consider the sequence (0, 0, 1): in this case the probability of having 1 is 3/N (because we had two 0 before)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer / too long for a comment.

Here are some numerical results:

```
  N    E[Y]
  1  1.000000
  2  1.250000
  3  1.444444
  4  1.621094
  5  1.785920
  6  1.940608
  7  2.086209
  8  2.223695
  9  2.353993
 10  2.477955
 11  2.596337
 12  2.709795
 13  2.818884
 14  2.924076
 15  3.025769
 16  3.124298
 17  3.219949
 18  3.312966
 19  3.403559
 20  3.491909
 21  3.578177
 22  3.662504
 23  3.745014
 24  3.825820
 25  3.905022
 26  3.982712
 27  4.058972
 28  4.133878
```

The growth rate seems to be $E[Y] \propto N^{0.4494}$, so an upperbound of $\sqrt{N}$ seems plausible.